# Supertab or Jedi for Python Autocompletion

Tags: plugin-jedi-vim, plugin-supertab

I'm trying to add a good Tab autocompletion plugin for VIM and I've found [Jedi](https://github.com/davidhalter/jedi-vim), but on its docs it says to use [Supertab](https://github.com/ervandew/supertab).

I don't understand the difference between the two. I'm writing Python and I would like tab completion. Why should I use one or the other?

Comment: Another option: [YouCompleteMe](https://github.com/Valloric/YouCompleteMe), which uses `Jedi` (for python) and replaces the `SuperTab` functionality.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not use Vim-Jedi but from what the doc says, the plugin allows completion using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Space</kbd>.

Supertab is another plugin which remaps <kbd>Tab</kbd> to a sensible autocomplete behavior.

The author only suggests to use supertab if you want to use the <kbd>Tab</kbd> key to trigger Vim-Jedi completion *(This is easier than remapping the key by
yourself in your `.vimrc`)*.

This means that you can use Vim-Jedi without supertab if you like its original completion with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Space</kbd>. IMO you should just give Vim-Jedi a try without supertab and when you're comfortable with it, you'll see if you want to use supertab and make your choice.

Comment: Ah ok I get it now. Thanks for the elementary explanation.